# Selenium - I have defined my driver in a singleton class and if i try to run my testcases in parallel its not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium - I have defined my driver in a singleton class and used that driver in multiple classes. Now if i run the classes in series it's working fine, But if i try to run the classes in parallel it's not working.

For eg : if i give the thread count as 2 only one browser is opened.

How to run the testcases in parallel using singleton class?

Singleton class :

```
public class SingletonDesignPattern {
private static Utilities obj;

private SingletonDesignPattern() {

}

public static Utilities getInstance() {

    if(obj == null) {

        obj = new Utilities();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Driver class:

```
public class Driver {

public static WebDriver driver;
public static Utilities util = SingletonDesignPattern.getInstance();


public String currentdate = null;
Test_action test = new Test_action();

@BeforeSuite
public void execute_test() throws Exception {
    try {

        driver = util.initializeDriver();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@BeforeTest
public void beforebacklog() throws Exception
{

    util.getlogin();

}

@AfterSuite
public void quit() throws Exception {

     driver.quit();
}
}
```

Comment: When you try to run the classes in parallel does it open multiple browser windows? can you post your code here?

Comment: No, only single browser is opened.

Comment: Why the need for a singleton class? Add the relevant code

Comment: one driver == one browser. If you want parallel tests you will need several browsers, so several drivers...

Comment: @Grasshopper : I dont want to add the driver cases in all my classes. I thought on initialising it in one place and call in all my classes.

Comment: @lokesh If you use this singelton, the way to run in parallel is to use jvm forks configuration in maven failsafe or surefire plugin...